# Write String with quotations into txt file on Python

Tags: python, csv, txt

I am reading a line from a .csv file and want to write that into a .txt file

This is what is in the .csv file: `123,"123456789abc"`

I read the .csv file with this:

```
with open('test.csv', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    data_old = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    for row_old in data_old:
        old_file= {}
        old_file['first'] = row_old[0]
        old_file['second'] = row_old[1]
        line_to_write.append(old_file)
```

This is what I am writing it into the .txt file:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as g:
    writer = csv.writer(g, lineterminator="\n") # Read csv file
    for new_file in line_to_write:
        writer.writerow(new_file['first'], new_file['second'])
```

My expected output on test.txt is this: `123,"123456789abc"`
But it writes into test.txt this: `123,123456789abc`

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can just pass `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` when you create the `csv.writer` object:

```
writer = writer = csv.writer(g, lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

Comment: @Santos because that is *a `str`*, if you want it to be treated as numeric, you need to make it a number. So when you *read* from the csv, do `old_file['first'] = int(row_old[0])`

Comment: Thanks after changing the first column into an integer, it worked!